# Python given a list of strings and a list of substrings, count the occurrences of each substring?

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

I have a huge list of strings and a list of target phrases and I want to count the number of each target phrase occurrences within the list of strings.

```
full_text = []
with open ("hindu_texts.txt", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        line = line.split("~")
        current = line[1].replace("\n","")
        full_text.append(current)

list_gods = []
with open ("C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Fall_2022/hindu_gods.txt", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if '~' not in line and line != "\n":
            list_gods.append(line.replace("\n",""))
            
text_data = pd.DataFrame({'words' : full_text})
pattern = '|'.join(list_gods)

text_data.words.str.count(pattern)
```

currently I have clunky code that outputs the number of matching substrings but I do not know how to find out which substring(s) is/are the one(s) that matched

Comment: Can you write code that counts the number of occurrences of a single string? If you repeat that process for every string, why does that not solve the problem?

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more efficient way since I am looking for about 500 target phrases out of a list of 25,000 strings.